# $\operatorname{STop}_{n,n-2}\simeq S^1$?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, smoothing-theory

$\DeclareMathOperator\STop{STop}$I am interested in any information about the homotopy type of the groups $\STop_{n,j}$ of homeomorphisms of $R^n$ preserving orientation and pointwise $R^j\subset R^n$. It is easy to see that $\STop_{n,n-1}$ is contractible, being homeomorphic to the square of the group of relative-to-the-boundary homeomorphisms of a disc. But what about $\STop_{n,n-2}$? How does it compare to $S^1$? At least for $n=3$ the answer is probably known.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The general result in this direction is due to Kirby-Siebenmann, Theorem B of [Normal bundles for codimension 2 locally flat imbeddings](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/BFb0066125): the map

$$\mathrm{SO}(2) \longrightarrow \mathrm{STop}_{n,n-2}$$

is $(n-2)$-connected. (They state this for $n \neq 4$ but it is true in this case as well by the corresponding result for codimension 2 normal bundles due to Freedman-Quinn.)

Comment: Thank you, this is very interesting. So, it's not known when these groups are equivalent to $S^1$? Even for $n=3$?

Comment: My question is related to the following problem. Keichi Sakai in his 2014 paper "Deloopings of the spaces of embeddings" showed that as an immediate consequence of Lashof's work $$\operatorname{hofiber}(\operatorname{Emb}_\partial(D^m,D^n)\to\operatorname{Imm}_\partial(D^m,D^n))\simeq\Omega^{m+1}V_{n,m}^t,$$ where $V_{n,m}^t=Top_n/Top_{n,m}$, for $n\geq 5$, $n-m\geq 3$. The fact is also true for $n-m\leq1$. I believe that properly understood the statement holds for $n-m=2$ as well. Namely, if we take into account only the components of homotopy invertible knots.

Comment: It is known that the maximal subgroup $\pi_0 ^\times\operatorname{Emb}_\partial(D^{n-2},D^n)\subset \pi_0 \operatorname{Emb}_\partial(D^{n-2},D^n)$ is isomorphic to $\Theta_{n-1}$, $n\geq 5$. The invertible elements appear as reparametrizations of the trivial knot. This is to explain why I asked this question. The statement would be true if one can show that the component of the trivial knot in $\operatorname{Emb}^t_\partial(D^{n-2},D^n)$ is contractible.

Comment: The space $\operatorname{Emb}^t_\partial(D^{n-2},D^n)$ is understood as the simplicial set of isotopies satisfying the local ambient isotopy extension property, see https://projecteuclid-org.er.lib.k-state.edu/journals/illinois-journal-of-mathematics/volume-20/issue-1/Embedding-spaces/10.1215/ijm/1256050168.full. If one can show that the local isotopy exension property implies the global isotopy extension property, then this would imply that the component of the inclusion in $\operatorname{Emb}^t_\partial(D^{n-2},D^n)$ is equivalent to $Homeo_\partial(D^n)/Homeo_\partial(D^n,D^{n-2})$.

Comment: And therefore is contractible.

Comment: In a comment to another question on this cite you mentioned that the groups $\pi_i(\operatorname{Emb}_\partial(D^{n-2},D^n),\iota)$ are not finitely generated for some $n$ and $i$. Can you give me a reference?

Comment: I believe it is a weak equivalence for n=3. It is true that the component of the trivial knot in $\mathrm{Emb}^t_\partial(D^{n-2},D^n)$ is weakly contractible; as you suggest, this is a consequence of the Alexander trick and isotopy extension (you should define $\mathrm{Emb}^t$ here as the simplicial set of locally flat embeddings; this has isotopy extension by Corollary 1.4 of Edwards-Kirby). For the statement that those homotopy groups need not be finitely generated, see Example 6.6 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/2103.13468.pdf or Theorem 10.1 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1912.09029.pdf.

Comment: I don't think that the Alexander trick works in codimension 2. It does when codimension is different from 2 and ambient dimension is $>4$ by the work of Chernavskii. It also works when codimension is 1 and ambient dimension is $\neq 4$ by a work of Hudson. Of course, it always work when codimension is 0. However, it is still likely that $\operatorname{Emb}^t_\partial(D^{n-2},D^n)$ is weakly contractible, which would imply that $\operatorname{Top}_{n,n-2}$ has non-finitely generated homotopy groups and thus is not equivalent to $S^1$, $n>4$.

Comment: One would need to show that $\operatorname{Emb}^t_\partial(D^{n-2},D^n)=\operatorname{Homeo}_\partial(D^n)/\operatorname{Homeo}_{\partial\cup D^{n-2}}(D^n)$ as simplicial sets. (Both simplicial groups of the right-hand side have contractible realizations by the Alexander trick.) This would require a statement that any $i$-parametric locally flat isotopy (in the sense of Lashof) $\Delta^k\times D^{n-2}\to \Delta^k\times D^n$ can be covered by an ambient isotopy. Kirby-Edwards Corollary 1.4 proves it only for 1-simplices. But possibly the proof can be generalized to simplices of any dimension.

Comment: Let's continue the discussion by email?

Comment: OK, I will email you.